# EOFError when calling Geocoder method in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eof, rails-geocoder

So I tried to submit a location-based search by providing a city to my Geocoder method `Geocoder.coordinates("Miami")`, but my Rails app threw this exception:

```
EOFError in ListingsController#search

end of file reached
```

My development log doesn't really explain what's going on:

[image]

And my code cuts off and throws the exception at the Geocoder call in my controller:

```
def search
  @favorited_listing = FavoritedListing.new
  @listings = Listing.search(params[:search].downcase)
  @results = Array.new
  @cityCoordinates = Geocoder.coordinates(params[:city])  # <= This is where the exception gets thrown



  if !params[:city].nil? && params[:city] != ""
    @results = @listings.select { |listing| listing.location.distance_from(@cityCoordinates) < 50 }
  else
    @results = @listings
  end

  @listings_json = []

  @coordinates = @results.map do |listing|
    @listings_json << listing.as_json(:include => [:location, :pictures])
  end

  respond_with(@results)
end
```

Things I've tried from other posts about this issue:

- Removing Sprockets cache `rm -Rf tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/*`
- Cloning the project into a new directory from git

Neither of these have worked. Does anyone know what is happening or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran `bundle update` and it fixed the issue. I believe the problem was my `net-ssh` gem or `faraday` gem (most likely faraday in my opinion) causing a problem with trying to make http requests. I am going to look into it more and update this response when I learn some more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that Geocoder, geokit and geokit-rails all needed updating and that has fixed the problem of EoF exceptions.

Comment: Cheers! Any idea why this started happening? Saw the error come through over the last few days. Looks like the freegeoip it uses redirects to ipstack, so could be that?

Comment: @DamienRoche apparently so, I tried to check versions diff of geokit and geokit-rails but nothing major has changed.